# I got issue regarding memory limit, I have changed php.ini files. still got same error?

Tags: magento2, composer, memory-limit

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

> {"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Allowed
> memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096
> bytes)' in
> '/home/a1pro/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php'
> on line 121"

when i checked during command then it shows 128M only. but i have changed with php_value memory_limit 2048M .

Answer (score 0):

There are two other Magento 2 files that might override your default `php.ini` settings

1. magentoroot/.user.ini
2. magentoroot/.htaccess

Check these files for existing `php_value memory_limit` settings and modify as needed.

Comment: I have changed in these files but still if i checked via command it will show 128M.

Comment: from the command line do php -i (or use phpinfo() via a web page) and check the configured location of php.ini - make sure you are editing the correct php,ini file!